# How to share images and description on Twitter and Facebook using `react-share` package?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, npm

This is my helmet code for this one.

```
<Helmet>
  <meta property="og:image" content={shareImg} />
  <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content={shareImg} />
</Helmet>
```

This code snippet for Twitter and Facebook share buttons.

```
<li>
  <TwitterShareButton
    url={shareURL}
    title={shareTitle}
    className="social-icons"
  >
    <TwitterIcon size={24} />
  </TwitterShareButton>
</li>
<li>
  <FacebookShareButton
    url={shareURL}
    quote={shareTitle}
    className="social-icons"
>
    <FacebookIcon size={24} />
  </FacebookShareButton>
</li>
```

But it is not working. It would be great if anyone can help this issue.

Comment: *"Is not working"* is a virtually meaningless problem statement. Be specific about what does and what does not work and what expected behavior is and how your code differs from that

Comment: Images and descriptions sharing is not working. Also tweeting is not working.

Comment: That is not a code specific problem

Comment: Actually, I also think code looks fine and did my best with react-share package.
Is there any alternative way or packages for this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for Facebook and Twitter to show a preview of your page incl. images, title etc. you will need to have server-side-rendering.

You can accomplish that by leveraging libraries such as NextJS, build it yourself with a NodeJS server or to make it super simple & quick you can use www.prerender.io. It will crawl your pages & will serve a server-side-rendered page to all crawlers and social media platforms.